# I need to extract from a RSS the mp3 file linked in each item

Tags: drupal, feed

I'm trying to import a Feedburner RSS. Each post is composed by a title and a description. Within that description there is a mp3 link. The link could be in any part of the text.

Is there a way to extract the mp3 link and place it in a (drupal) field link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Feeds (http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module and Feeds Tamper (http://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) you can get the description and then find the link using a tamper (custom or a regexp). The mapping is then done by Feeds module.